# Tapping on notification redirects to random question

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, ios-app

Tapping on a notification (**inbox**, not achievements) on my iPad's **StackExchange App**, sometimes redirects me to a random question.
Please fix.
Or am I doing something wrong?

**Screenshots:**
I tapped on the **third** notification (image max-width).

[image: notifications]

This is where I (obviously) **wanted** to get.

[image: the correct question]

This is where I was **redirected** to.

[image: random question]

> **Notes:**
>   It doesn't happen **every** time.
>   When it does, I see the **correct** question for a second, then I'm **redirected**.
>   **App version:** 1.4.0, iPad 2.
>   **Links** to questions used in **screenshots**:
>   [Correct (intended) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712392/image-max-width-not-being-applied).
>   [Random to which I got redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33720162/5306470).

Comment: What you mean random? Please give example, what post was the notification actually about, and where you got when tapping it.

Comment: Could you provide some general info like the app version, and probably your device model and iOS version? And also, include the link to the post on screenshot to make it easier to investigate the issue.

Comment: Is it only happening on that one question?  Is is always taking you to that same wrong question or new ones each time?  Is it happening on both the inbox item for a new comment and and a new answer?  Does it happen only in landscape or also portrait?

Comment: Are you still able to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.3.2.

The issue is that when you select a question on iPad, in landscape, which is on a different site than the last selected site:

1. The app loaded a screen with the question list and placed it under the question in the navigation stack.
2. The question list finished loading and observed that there was no selected question.
3. Because the question list was visible and no question was selected, it selected the first question and requested its display in a "push or set right controller" function.
4. This function saw that the split controller wasn't the root controller and pushed a new view controller for the first question in the list, on top of the question you were interested in.

The logic has been reworked so the split list will only try setting the right side when visible.

Comment: It's your call.  You could wait for it to ship to the app store or the [beta channel](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270528/stack-exchange-ios-app-beta-moving-to-test-flight) or accept now so you don't forget.