# Incorrect year text

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I have up voted answer some month ago, now I just tried to toggle it, throws correct error message, but incorrect year as seen in pic below

Thanks, see you soon

- App Version: 1.4.2.3
- Device: iPhone 5 (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.2 (Build 13C75)

[image: voting on locked answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.3.5.

The app uses [unsafe filters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) when performing API calls, so I had assumed `error_message` would be an unsafe string since it's not annotated "unchanged with unsafe filters".

That said, the docs actually say:

> The error_* fields, while technically elligible for filtering, will not actually be excluded in an error case. This is by design.

In talking with Kevin, since an error occurred we can't assume that the filter is valid so it is completely ignored, both for field filtering and safe-vs-unsafe strings.  I'm now applying HTML decoding at the alert UI.

Comment: Worth noting when 1.4.3.5 build coming

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly It's in [the beta channel](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270528/235711) now and will ship to the App Store sometime this month.