# Can't download the iOS app in TestFlight

Tags: support, ios-app

[image]

I just recently reset my iPad and restore it with my backup, and now I can't download the app anymore. I have searched for the old invitation for the beta link but it doesn't work. I have trouble to access the US Store so currently I'm in the Vietnam Store.

Comment: Is TestFlight for apps that are still being tested?

Comment: You should download the official app from the App Store.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to use the beta channel, you have to re-enroll as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270528/stack-exchange-ios-app-beta-moving-to-test-flight). ([direct link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeCOB3qyWG0XcpFzXBP1wrvVv3GtHYC9r0xBrBGB4rNdT4r4g/viewform))

Comment: @ShadowWizard isn't using the old link I have equivalent to re-enrolling for a new one? I have clicked on the old link, but this still happens

Comment: Not sure, but I think that if switching devices (or doing a hard reset) you need to re-enroll as it's using some unique per-device key.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the enrollment form only requires me to fill in my email and my account in SE, so I don't think the device doesn't attach to the download link.

Comment: Well, guess we have to wait until beta channel next deploy to see if the answer is correct. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard 4 days have passed. Too long :(

Comment: 4 days?? Android app didn't get a bit of attention for 4 **months**, I don't even dare to dream when it will get new version. (Probably never... so consider yourself lucky for using a live app :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard another reason to switch to iOS :P. (I'm not an iFan, I prefer an Android). I also feel bad for you because of your agony, but I can't stop laughing when reading your rant. Yeah, feeling like a lucky one =))

Comment: Yeah yeah, laugh all you want.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any builds available now, so you can't download it.

[image]

You'll need to wait for a new beta release before being able to download it.

Source: I'm also enrolled in the TestFlight beta

Comment: can't I download the current build?

Comment: @Ooker No, it's not possible