# iOS beta app has expired

Tags: discussion, ios-app

I'm using the beta app and it's expired. Is a new release coming soon or should I just erase and install the App Store version? Is there somewhere public that development of the app is planned and discussed?

[image: Test Flight Screenshot]

Comment: "Is there somewhere public that development of the app is planned and discussed?" No.

Comment: Did you ever [switch over to the Test Flight system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270528/stack-exchange-ios-app-beta-moving-to-test-flight)?

Comment: @animuson yes I've been on it a few month now.

Comment: Same issue for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working on getting it back up right now.  I've been knee deep in a refactoring + POC project for I guess exactly 61 days now and just haven't been ready to ship.

Comment: And there it is! Thanks.

Comment: It's happened again!

Comment: @miken32 :( it's in the beta review queue right now.